# How to prevent strategy looking at premarket bars using pinescript in tradingview?

Tags: pine-script

I have `t = time(timeframe.period, "1430-2100:12345")`

But when my strategy counts previous bars at the start of the day it counts/looks at premarket bars.

I'm trading and index where I cannot turn off extended hours in the settings so is there a way to make the code ignore premarket bars?

`strategy("testing", overlay = true)

t = time(timeframe.period, "1430-2100:12345")

buy  = low < low[1] and t
sell = high > high[2] and t

short = high > high[1] and t
cover = low < low[2] and t

strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long, 1, when = buy)
strategy.close("Long Entry", when = sell)

strategy.entry("Short Entry", strategy.short, 1, when = short)
strategy.close("Short Entry", when = cover)

if (not t)
strategy.close_all()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `session.ismarket` or `session.ispremarket` built-in variables.

For example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script")

t = time(timeframe.period, "0900-2100:12345")
b = session.ismarket and t

plot(b ? 1 : 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunatly it did not work for me. Here's a sample of what my code looks like.

`strategy("testing", overlay = true)

t = time(timeframe.period, "1430-2100:12345")

buy  = low < low[1] and t
sell = high > high[2] and t

short = high > high[1] and t
cover = low < low[2] and t

strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long, 1, when = buy)
strategy.close("Long Entry", when = sell)

strategy.entry("Short Entry", strategy.short, 1, when = short)
strategy.close("Short Entry", when = cover)

if (not t)
    strategy.close_all()`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. It is unreadable as it is. Also, please attach a screenshot and show us the issue.

Comment: I tried placing in it in a code format above with `` but it didn't seem to work but you can see the code now